# Spring Boot REST API startup delay when FIPS introduced

Tags: spring-security, fips

When we start up our Spring Boot API, there's a very long delay between the `RepositoryConfigurationDelegate` step and the `PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate` step. I've modified the dates below for readability, but they reflect the roughly 2.5 hour delay we’re seeing:

```
2023-05-17 08:00:00.123 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository 
 scanning in 97 ms. Found 24 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-17 10:30:00.123 INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 
 'methodSecurityConfig' of type [com.deloitte.tve.MethodSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90e69ca] is 
 not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-05-17 10:30:00.456 INFO  o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
```

This delay only starts occurring after some kind of FIPS setting is added to the server. I don’t yet know the specific setting change, but the thread dump shows activity related to [pkcs11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.html).

The strange thing is we’re not specifically using pkcs11 in the Java code. Yet it seems clear that adding FIPS is at least in part the cause of the API startup delay.

Any idea why this would be? Is it possible the default Spring Security configuration needs to be tweaked in some way to take into account that FIPS was added to the server?

We’re using jdk8u372 and spring boot 2.6.8.